# Batch job working from backend but through autosys shows class not found

Tags: java, linux, classpath

My problem is
I am running my batch job through autosys and it throws **noclassdeffounderror** and **classnotfoundexception**.
I know this is related to classpath. My classpath is broken somehow.
I have done everything to fix it but no luck.

Below is my command which I am using in Linux shell script

Export csv_classpath=.:/csv/home/path/lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar:/csv/home/path/app.jar:/csv/home/path:

Java -classpath "$csv_classpath" my.main.newfile arg0

Just to note it working perfectly fine when I run it in backend but it only shows error while through autosys

Kindly help

Comment: share the autosys job definition - is the user in autosys job def same as your test user - is there access to /csv/home ?  just add some debug lines to the script - `ls` on the paths (/csv/home/path/lib, /csv/home/path)

Comment: Yes autosys user is same and I've check Jil file of autosys multiple times. Looks no issue in that. It looks like my classpath are getting overridden everytime. And Strange thing is the same was working perfectly fine on another server